# Classic ASP: Server.CreateObject not supported

Tags: createobject

When I call Server.CreateObject(), from my Classic ASP page, I get

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01B6)
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I've tried the following (separately):

```
Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Server.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
```

I know the ActiveX objects are installed because the following javascript calls work

```
var test = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
var test = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
var test = new ActiveXObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
```

I'm calling it from my localhost IIS server. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: How do you know the Javascript call is working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do the following:

```
Dim x: x = Server.CreateObject("My.ProgID.Here")
```

...VBScript creates the object and then attempts to access the default property for storing in 'x'. Since none of these objects have a default property defined (specifically an IDispatch-based property with [id(DISPID_VALUE)]), this fails with "Object doesn't support this property or method".

What you actually want is this:

```
Dim x: Set x = Server.CreateObject("My.ProgID.Here")
```

Comment: This solution worked!  When I wrote similar code run on a different server, I didn't have the same problem.  I'm not sure why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

Or downloading this component and installing on your webserver?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3144B72B-B4F2-46DA-B4B6-C5D7485F2B42&displaylang=en

Then restarting the server and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Calling them from the browser doesn't mean that they are installed in IIS.